# Validate a input dict schema

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a schema for a input dict in Python that goes like this,

```
SCHEMA = {
    'mode': ('mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'),
    'method': ('method_1', 'method_2'),
    'other': {
        'x1': [1, 365],
        'x2': [0., 1.0]
    }

}
```

I want to validate the given input dict,

```
inp = {
    'mode': 'mode_1',
    'method': 'method_1',
    'other': {
        'x1': 1,
        'x2': 1.0
    }

}
```

1. Contains the same keys
2. If any of the value is a dict check that dict too have same keys
3. Check the values of input dict are in the schema range. For example, for the key 'mode' the input dict should have value from `('mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3')`. Like wise for all the key-value pair.
4. If the type of a value in SCHEMA is a list, I also want to check the corresponding value from the input dict is greater than value[0] and less than value[1]

I can think about doing it with loops. But can't think of a generalized way to do it. If I just looped over the two dicts and compared the values, I have to rewrite the logic if the schema changes.

Is there any straight forward way to validate the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this recursive function:

```
def validate(input_, db): 
    for k,v in input_.items(): 
        if isinstance(v, dict): 
            return validate(v, db.get(k)) 
        else: 
            if v not in db.get(k): 
                return False 
    return True
```

Then you call it:

```
In [21]: validate(inp, SCHEMA)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[21]: True
```

if you change your inp to:

```
In [16]: inp = { 
    ...:     'mode': 'mode_2', 
    ...:     'method': 'method_2', 
    ...:     'other': { 
    ...:         'x1': 4, # This is not valid
    ...:         'x2': 1.0 
    ...:     } 
    ...:  
    ...: }                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [17]: validate(inp, SCHEMA)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[17]: False
```

or

```
In [20]: inp = { 
    ...:     'mode': 'mode_2', 
    ...:     'method': 'method_2', 
    ...:     'other': { 
    ...:         'x1': 1, 
    ...:         'x2': 1.0 
    ...:     } 
    ...:  
    ...: }                                                                                                                                                                                                         
In [21]: validate(inp, SCHEMA)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[21]: True
```

Comment: Nice solution based on recursion. It can serve my purpose. But my SCHEMA can be of any level of nesting. Average nesting is ~1000. I doubt the efficiency of the function with high amount of nesting.

Comment: Updated the Q with a condition I was missing earlier.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary are like json so you can use jsonschema:

```
 import json

 from jsonschema import validate

 # A sample schema, YOU WILL HAVE TO DESIGN ONE .
 schema = {
     "type" : "object",
     "properties" : {
         "price" : {"type" : "number"},
         "name" : {"type" : "string"},
     },
 }
```

TESTING

```
# If no exception is raised by validate(), the instance is valid.
validate(instance={"name" : "Eggs", "price" : 34.99}, schema=schema)



validate(instance={"name" : "Eggs", "price" : "Invalid"}, schema=schema) 

#error

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValidationError: 'Invalid' is not of type 'number'
```

For more details check the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/).

To get valid Json Schema for your schema you can use [this](https://jsonschema.net/).

Just replace `' with " and () with []`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion:

```
SCHEMA = {'mode': ('mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'), 'method': ('method_1', 'method_2'), 'other': {'x1': [1, 365], 'x2': [0.0, 1.0]}}
inp = {'mode': 'mode_1', 'method': 'method_1', 'other': {'x1': 1, 'x2': 1.0}}
def check(d, s):
    return all(b in s[a] if not isinstance(b, dict) else check(b, s[a]) for a, b in d.items())

print(check(inp, SCHEMA))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Edit: the solution above simply checks that a single key exists in an iterable of valid keys. However, to handle more specific checks (such as your fourth condition), you can build handlers for different types:

```
t = {'tuple':lambda x, y:x in y, 'list':lambda x, y:x > y[0] and x < y[-1]}
def check(d, s):
   return all(check(b, s[a]) if isinstance(b, dict) else t[type(s[a]).__name__](b, s[a]) for a, b in d.items())
```